# This MySQL syntax is honky, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt... (seriously)

Tags: php, mysql

Check this out:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) { 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("TagDB");

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE friendtable SET state = '1' 
    WHERE (userB = '$username' AND state = '0')");
```

This should simply update a table to show a state of 1 for every instance the userB column consists of the posted username. However, this only works sometimes. Without changing any code whatsoever, this method will sometimes to as it ought to, and other times do nothing. Strange.

```
if (isset($_POST['state'])) {
    $state = $_POST['state'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}

if (isset($_POST['frienduser'])) {
    $frienduser = $_POST['frienduser'];
}

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("TagDB");

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE friendtable SET state = '$state' WHERE (userA = '$frienduser' AND userB = '$username')");
```

This does the same. Sometimes its perfect, other times, no change. I have no idea what could be different. My only lead is that I sometimes manually change values in MySQL via phpmyadmin to test some stuff. Could it be getting confused because I'm putting in some values manually? I wouldn't think so, but its the only lead I have. Take a look at the code and see if you can spot anything that would cause this strange issue, if you have the time. Thank you.

Comment: Offtopic: You have some serious SQL Injection vulnerabilities in there with using $_POST variables without escaping.

Comment: If you use prepared statements, this problem should not exist.

Comment: Are you sure you entered the correct username and not some spaces/tabs/newlines around it?

Comment: What is AUTOCOMMIT set to?  How do you know the query isn't updating all rows?  What does mysql_affected_rows() say about your UPDATE?  What does a SELECT with the same WHERE clause reveal, before and after UPDATE?

Comment: @Dogbert yea I know, I'm just building a basic framework before I go through and clean that stuff up. The solution to this problem is below, I'm going to close the question now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a complete idiot. I'm posting this as an answer to help anyone who may run into this problem too. Basically, I would change the state to 0 to check if various inputs worked. I'd then refresh the page to see if the state had changed after I had made an input. However, when refreshing the page it refreshed my previous mysql request.... to set the state to 0. So by refreshing I was really undoing what I had just done. Sorry to bother you all with this, but hopefully this post will serve someone else in the future. Thanks!